# How to ignore password protected or encrypted documents when calling CTX_DOC.SNIPPET in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, plsql

I need help! I am running into errors when i do a document text search using CTX_DOC.SNIPPET against one of our tables. Given the nature of the application and indexes, i can't isolate documents to be searched against manually and to detect the troublesome file, i will literally have to loop through each document (where document count is over 10,000).

How can i have Oracle ignore the corrupted, password protected or encrypted file when CTX_DOC.SNIPPET is called? I will rather oracle skip the document that has issues that throw an error that returns an application error to the user.

The errors i have seen using CTX_DOC.SNIPPET for certain search terms are as seen below! HELP!

```
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-11207: user filter command exited with status 1
DRG-11221: Third-party filter indicates this document is corrupted.
ORA-06512: at "CO_ADMIN.PKG_SEARCH", line 798
ORA-06512: at line 62

ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-11207: user filter command exited with status 1
DRG-11223: Third-party filter indicates this document is password protected or encrypted.
DRG-50901: text query parser syntax error on line 1, column 8  
ORA-06512: at "CO_ADMIN.PKG_SEARCH", line 799
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I read up some more on this and the effort it would take to automatically password protected or encrypted files excluded from indexing using the auto_filter would have been too much work for the timeline we have.

Perhaps in the future, the table would have a column that indicates which column can be ignored.

In the meantime, i rewrote the code to simply ignore these files anytime an attempt is made on a corrupted, encrypted or password protected file.

Perhaps in the future, files would be reviewed to make sure they arent corrupted at least before uploading into the system